# Can you define navigators based on user type, and conditionally declare them in the root navigator?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Im looking to declare a different navigator based on the user type which is known after login.

The below is just an example :

```
const authNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Login: LoginScreen,
    Register: RegisterScreen,
};

const studentNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Home: StudentHomeScreen,
    Professors: ProfessorListScreen
});

const professorNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Home: ProfessorHomeScreen,
    Students: StudentListScreen
});

const rootNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
    Auth: authNavigator,
    App: isStudent ? studentNavigator : professorNavigator,
});
```

`isStudent` would be set in redux state after login.
I've tried a couple things like wrapping up the Student/Professor navigator into a react component which takes redux state then conditionally rendering it. But with the latest update to react-navigation, we cant render multiple navigators.
Next i tried declaring the below:

```
const rootNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
    Auth: authNavigator,
    StudentHome: studentNavigator,
    ProfessorHome: professorNavigator
});
```

Then i'd route to StudentHome/ProfessorHome based on user type. But this doesnt work because the navigator loads up all screens so if a student logs in, the professor screens are also loaded which causes issues since the redux state is different and causes undefined errors. And i've also noticed lazyLoad was removed from the new version.

I'm just looking for the best way to implement this use case.